# POST call does not work correctly

Tags: php, html, api, rest, post

I am currently working on a project and trying to do a POST call. The API documentation says the following

```
POST https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood HTTP/1.1
Host: jawbone.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
title=MoodTest&sub_type=2
```

My code is:

```
$url = "http://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood";
$data = array('title' => 'moodTest', 'sub_type' => 2);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
'http' => array(
           'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           'method'  => 'POST',
           'content' => http_build_query($data)
       ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

title and sub_type are needed for changing the specific data.
I get the following error:

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(http://...@me/mood): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\main.php on line 53
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0028  265776  {main}( )   ..\main.php:0
2   0.9006  268584  postMood( ) ..\main.php:15
3   0.9007  271680  file_get_contents ( )   ..\main.php:53
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to change the url to: https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood (with https instead of http)

Comment: Sadly it does not change anything

Comment: Did you change the 'http' => array( to 'https'?

Comment: I would use xhr request instead of you...

Comment: And how should I do that? (Btw.: the POST call to the server accepts only JSON)

Comment: Your code is php right?

Comment: Do you have file_get_contents allowed for usage when reaching some remote webpage?

Comment: I do not really understand your question, sorry?

Comment: @Jan, I imagine it could not return a reason code of 404 (not found) if remote HTTP fetching was disabled.

Comment: @halfer, I believe that you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're issue seems to be that you are not authenticated.

If you open this request:

> https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood?title=asd&sub_type=2

on your browser, you will see the details of the error. If you check the headers in the response, you see that the status code is "404 Not Found".

I would suggest you to check the documentation of the API about how to authenticate or maybe switch to a supported API version (as the message of the response is "Unsupported API version 1.1, unless called with an OAuth header").

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that the message is missleading. However I do not believe the authentication is the problem as the GET requests work perfectly fine and they also need an authentication before.

Comment: I am currently using Postman to try to generate a POST request with the documentation you provided but I'm not possible to get anything different than that response. Are you able to generate the post request somehow(differently than with php)?

Comment: To make API calls you need an account at Jawbone, maybe that's why? Sadly I am not able to generate the post request in another way.. (the doc to the API: https://jawbone.com/up/developer)

Comment: Thats the issue, on your stream_context_create options, you are not providing any authentication on the header.

Comment: At GET requests I have it like this: 'header' => "Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}\r\n" .... however, as you can see in my first post, the header has now that "Content-Type" thing.. how do I have to change it?

Comment: You can change header to an array 
`'header'  => array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}"),`
or you can try like this:
`"header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Bearer {$access_token}\r\n",`

Comment: Are you sure your access token is correctly set? maybe try to generate that post request with your access_token using a tool such as postman and see if everything is fine?

Comment: Alright. Your solution is correct. The only thing that happened was that someone told me to change "http" to "https"... changing it back made things work fine! I don't know why one letter can make such a change and I don't know why this actually solved it but well. Thank you very much and also thanks to the others who helped!

Comment: I think its very important to understand whats going on under the hood. My suggestion would be to read a bit more about https [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) and feel free to ask about any other magical thing that is happening :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69556/discussion-between-user3549524-and-bardh-lohaj).

Answer (score 0):

use javascript:

```
function getJson() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("get", "https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood", true);
            xhr.onload = function(){
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Won't this bump into the Same Origin policy?

Comment: @halfer it's shouldn't. Im using the same script for website I developed and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in php to POST is to use curl (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php)

so in your case you can use example (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php#98628) :

```
function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array()) 
{ 
    $defaults = array( 
        CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, 
        CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post) 
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults)); 
    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
    { 
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
    } 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result; 
} 

$url = "http://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/mood";
$data = array('title' => 'moodTest', 'sub_type' => 2);

$result = curl_post($url, $data);
```

Comment: I only get a Notice back and with var_dump it shows me an empty string

Comment: @user3549524: what is the notice to which you refer?

Comment: try to change `trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); ` to `var_dump(curl_error($ch));`

Comment: That shows me an empty string. @halfer: those are away now

Comment: by the way, just opened this url in browser it returns {"meta": {"error_detail": "Unsupported API version 1.1, unless called with an OAuth header", "code": 404, "error_type": "endpoint_error", "time": 1422207074, "message": "Not Found", "user_xid": ""}, "data": {}}

Comment: are you sure that you've read documentation for your API completely?